# Executing View/Read Functions on Gnosis Safe with "Raw" Encoded Data

Tags: solidity, gnosis-safe, gnosis

I'm trying to execute an ERC721 "ownerOf" function through the Gnosis Safe interface`function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (address)`. When I use the Gnosis interface it works fine and I am returned the address of the owner.

But when I use the "Custom Data (hex encoded)" option, pass in custom data to do the exact same thing and execute the transaction (which costs gas) , I see the transaction in my history and on Etherscan but don't see the result anywhere. Is there anyway to execute a raw transaction and get the results for who the owner of the NFT is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view` functions on contract are meant to retrieve information. The Safe interface makes this possible and allows you to see the returned information. Solidity does not allow state changes in `view` functions (see [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/contracts.html#view-functions))

Transactions are meant to perform state changes on the blockchain (e.g. transfer ownership). Additionally transactions do not have a return value (only a success flag).

Therefore invoking a `view` functions via a transaction does not really make sense and just burns gas.

Consensys has a [blog post](https://consensys.net/blog/developers/guide-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-smart-contracts/) how to use view functions and events in smart contracts.